# Database couldn't update through Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to Edit my Database through Laravel Form. Edit do works but when i want to update the database it's showing the following Error.

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

here is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Course;

class courseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $alldata=Course::all();
        return  view('course.index',compact('alldata'));
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return view('course.create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        Course::create($input);
        return redirect('course');
    }   


    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $course=Course::findOrFail($id);
        return view('course.edit',compact('course'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        $data=Course::findOrFail($id);
        $data->update($input);
        return redirect('course');
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $data=Course::findOrFail($id);
        $data->delete($input);
        return redirect('course');
    }

}
```

Here is my Edit Page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title> Update Course </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" >
            <h3> Update course </h3>
        {!! Form::open(array('route' =>['course.update',$course->course_id],'class'=>'form-horizontal')) !!}
        {!! Form::token(); !!}
            <?php echo csrf_field(); ?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Course Code</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_code" class="form-control"  value="{{$course->course_code}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label >Course Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_title" class="form-control" value="{{$course->course_title}}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Course Credit</label>
                <input type="text" name="course_credit" class="form-control" value="{{$course->course_credit}}">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the route:

```
<?php

Route::resource('course','courseController');



Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

});
```

If anyone can solve the problem.please help.

Comment: use Redirect; in your controller

Comment: Below the statement use App\Course;

Comment: still showing the same Error

Comment: just to understand every things is working, only when you try to update you get the error?

Comment: yes. while trying to update i'm getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to edit you need to add method type according this [link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/124/opening-a-new-html-form).

> Specifying different methods
>
> You can use methods other than POST with your forms. Pass the 'method'
>   you want in the array argument. Valid methods are 'get', 'put',
>   'patch', 'post', or 'delete'.

So in your case you need to add `'method' => 'patch'` to your `Form::open..`

So your final code in blade will look like this:

```
{!! Form::open([
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'route' => ['course.update',$course->course_id],
    'class'=>'form-horizontal'
]) !!}
```

---

**Extra**
I can see you are using php tags like `<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>`, I assume you know in Laravel you can use `{{ csrf_field() }}` which is equal, but since I do not have in depth knowledge about your code, so it is left to you.